# Minimum number of files to input

Tags: html, file, input-field

When using `<input type="file" multiple>` is it possible to ask users to input at least `n` files?
Ex:  `<input type="file" min=5 multiple>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is required. Add an event listener to listen for the `change` event on the input, and check the number of uploaded files with `.files.length`.

```js
var uploader = document.querySelector('input');
var error = document.querySelector('p');
uploader.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if(uploader.files.length < 5){
    error.style.display='block';
  }
})
```

```css
#error{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple/>
<p id="error">Please upload at least 5 files</p>
```

Using it in a `form` to prevent submission if the number of uploaded files is less than 5:

```js
var uploader = document.querySelector('input');
var error = document.querySelector('p');
function validate(){
  if(uploader.files.length < 5){
    error.style.display='block';
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
#error{
  display:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<form action="somewhere.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type="file" multiple/>
<p id="error">Please upload at least 5 files</p>
<button>Submit files</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly you cannot have a minimum and a maximum amount of inputs the user can have. Might be added later but as of HTML5, this feature is not supported.

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_multiple.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple) for documentation on how to use the tag with it's features and limits.